# Determining cardinality and inverse

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let the function $\chi: P(Z) \to P(Z)$ be defined by $\chi(B) = B^c$ for any $B \in P(Z)$.

(In other words, $\chi$ sends a subset $ B \subseteq Z$  to its complement, $B^c$, i.e. the set $Z - B$.)

- (a) Prove that $\chi$ is a bijection.
- (b) Determine $\chi^{-1}$.

I do not really understand how to go about the part (a). I assume that it is injective because it is from $\chi: P(Z) \to P(Z)$ and defined by $\chi(B) = B^c$. So there is no distinct element of the domain mapping to the same codomain. For part (b) i assume its inverse is the same as the original function.

Answer (score 0):

The map is injective because no two sets have the same complement. The map is its own inverse, because the complement of the complement of a set is the set itself.

Comment: How would i determine the surjectivity?

Comment: Every set is the complement of some set. So $\chi$ is surjective.